# Trim a 360-degree GoPro Video in Linux?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, video-conversion

Is there a command line (or GUI) utility to trim a 360-degree *.mov file? The file was made using a GoPro Fusion Camera. I've tried `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -i File_A.mov -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:03:23 -c copy File_A_Trimmed.mov
```

but it converts a 360 video into a fishbowl video. I just want to clip a 4GB ffmpeg file from a specific start time to a specific end time.

Comment: "but it converts a 360 video into a fishbowl video." Please add the command you used. ffmpeg will export to what you tell it to export to so that seems odd to me :)

Comment: @Rinzwind: This is the command I entered. `ffmpeg -i File_A.mov -ss 00:00:00 -to 00:03:23 -c copy File_A_Trimmed.mov`. The output video came out "trimmed" but flattened (no longer 3D, the entire panorama was flattened out).

Comment: @guiverc: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.5

Comment: Is this an option? it is for downgrading 5k so it still will be 360: https://www.reddit.com/r/OculusGo/comments/dhxo3t/reencoding_high_quality_3d_videos_for_oculus_go/

Answer (score 0):

Install Losslesscut snap as follows:

```
sudo snap install losslesscut
```

See reference and further guidance on usage [here](https://www.maketecheasier.com/extract-clips-video-losslesscut/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=07092020) and product details [here](https://snapcraft.io/losslesscut).

Comment: Unfortunately, losslesscut turns the trimmed video into a fishbowl format video (i.e. it doesn't preserve the 3D nature of the video). I think losslesscut uses the same engine as ffmpeg, where I was also having this issue.